# sudo_exec returns nothing

Tags: php, linux, ping, shell-exec

I try to ping `www.google.de` with `shell_exec` and store the result into a variable but i get no result back from `shell_exec`.

```
<?php
    $ping           = 'sudo ping -c 4 ';
    $url            = 'www.google.de';

    $command        = $ping . $url;

    $ping_result    = shell_exec($command);

    $datei          = fopen("/var/www/myProject/result_ping","w") or die ("Could not open file!"); 
    sleep(10);

    if ($datei == false)
    {
        $ping_result = "Cannot open file!";
    }
    else
    {
        fwrite ($datei , $ping_result);
        fclose ($datei);
    }

    echo $command;      //Output:       sudo ping -c 4 www.google.de
    echo $ping_result;  //Output:       nothing
?>
```

The file `result_ping` has all rights (chmod 777).
Maybe the webserver is not allowed to execute `ping`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `2>&1` to your command to ensure you're not getting an error message that shell_exec would filter off:

```
$command        = $ping . $url . ' 2>&1';
```

`shell_exec` will return NULL in case of error. With that modification you redirect any error message to normal output, thus forcing shell_exec show every message you would normally get on a console session.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now i get: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified ` outputted on `ping_result` I will do my research.